# What is the difference between the async.compose function and underscore.compose function?

Tags: javascript, underscore.js, async.js

Both seem to be doing the same thing, i.e. calculating `f(g(h(x)))`, when called like this [`async.compose`](https://github.com/caolan/async#compose)`(f, g, h)` or [`_.compose`](http://underscorejs.org/#compose)`(f, g, h)`.

Is there any difference between the two calls ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As its name implies, `async.compose` composes *asynchronous* functions.

It gets the result via callback parameter, not return value.

Comment: So which of these is the preferred one and under which scenarios ?

Comment: @ChintanPathak: You need to understand what `async` means.

Answer (score 1):

I faced same situation where I needed one function I got from some lib to use the return value from `async.compose()` call. So I did wonder: How can one get the return value from `async.compose()`?
If you [write](https://github.com/caolan/async#compose):

```
var gotFromAsyncCompose = async.compose(
  function(gotParam, callback) {
    callback(null, 'hi ' + gotParam + '!';
  },
  function(name, callback) {
    callback(null, name.toUpperCase());
  }
);
var returnValue = gotFromAsyncCompose('moe', function(err, result){
  return result;
});
console.log(returnValue);
```

You'll get `undefined` as the value of `returnValue`.
So, `async.compose()` always return `undefined` as return value even if the last executed statement is `return 'A';`. You'll still get `undefined`!

When it comes to `_.compose()`, I [tried the same](http://underscorejs.org/#compose):

```
var w = _.compose(
  function(name){
    return 'hi '+name;
  },
  function(got){
    return got.toUpperCase() +'!';
  });
);
var returnValue = w('moe');
console.log(returnValue);
```

This time, you get `'hi MOE!'` as expected as the value of `returnValue`. You don't get `undefined` like the behaviour of `async.compose()`.

I didn't wrote any of these compose functions, but it seems that the difference between the two seems to be that `async.compose()` won't return any value whereas `_.compose()` will return the value you pass to `return` within the  last executed function.
But, there is another difference: `_.compose()` doesn't take care of any asynchronous call you make inside your functions. You have to write only synchronous code within all the functions that comprise your `_.compose()`.

**The four main differences I can see as of April 28th 2014 are**:

- async.compose() does **not** return a value
- async.compose() does take care of asynchronous calls within functions
- _.compose() does return a value
- _.compose() does **not** take care of asynchronous calls within functions